# JAWS and "true semantic headers" ( h1, h2, h3)

Tags: html, accessibility

Is it necessary to use h1, h2, and h3 tags for JAWS to read my website?

http://viget.com/inspire/a-designers-guide-to-accessibility-and-508-compliance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessary to use headings for a screen reader user to *read* it, but they certainly help with understanding and navigating a page, especially when there is a lot of content.

NB: Jaws is just one screen reader, NVDA and VoiceOver are other popular options.

The benefit they provide means they are considered necessary to meet WCAG at the AA level, is what Section 508 uses.

For the full reasoning I would see [the 'understanding' page from WCAG 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/content-structure-separation-programmatic.html) (which is what Section 508 will use soon).

For a simpler article, see this (old but still relevant) article for [how to use headings properly](http://www.nomensa.com/blog/2010/using-html-headings/).

Comment: Section 508 right now is based on WCAG1, but Dept of Justice Changes will likely soon update it to WCAG2.

Comment: Yea, it's been in the works for a long time. WCAG1 has heading use at AA, in WCAG2 it comes under "Info and relationships" http://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/content-structure-separation-programmatic.html which is also AA.

Answer (score 2):

Of course not, but it's a huge benefit to accessibility tool users if you do.  And since just about everybody else benefits too, e.g. through making your site easier to find appropriately in search engines, why would you not want to do it?

Comment: Not everyone is working on a greenfield project in which they have the option of using headings without a laborious markup and CSS refactor. For existing, complex content, it's expensive to refactor headings. It's still a huge benefit for assistive tech users, but it's not as simple as "why wouldn't you?".

Comment: Thank you, ckundo.  (This website is not accessible to the internet nor the general pubic.)